# javascript prototype - adding a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the javascript revealing prototype pattern, and I want to add a callback.  I'm trying something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qyhrb/2/

```
  var Refinements = function () { };

  Refinements.prototype = function () {
    Init = function () {
      $('.btn').click(Callback);
    },
    Callback = function(){
      alert('default function');
    };
    return { Init: Init, Callback : Callback };
  }();


   var refinements = new Refinements();
   refinements.Callback = function(){ alert('new method'); };
   refinements.Init();
```

Essentially what I want to do is pass a callback into the object and raise that callback when an event occurs.

Comment: What problems are you having? What are you expecting this code to do that it doesn't?

Comment: I want the alert('new method') to fire on btn.click instead of the alert('default function').

Comment: I would prefer a structure like this: http://jsfiddle.net/FUBxq/2/ - keep the callback function private and overriding it in the `init()` looks much cleaner to me.

Comment: @Christoph - Yes, as long as it's not something that might need to be changed later, that would be cleaner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    Init = function () {
        var refinement = this;
        $('.btn').click(refinement.Callback || Callback);
    },
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/FUBxq/)

Comment: it would prefer keeping the callback private and overriding it in the init function: http://jsfiddle.net/FUBxq/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var Refinements = function() {};

Refinements.prototype = function() {
  return {
    init: function() {
      $('.btn').click(this.callback);
    },
    callback: function() {
      alert('default function');
    }
  }
}();


var refinements = new Refinements();
refinements.callback = function() {
  alert('new method');
};
refinements.init();
```

Answer (score 1):

When I separated out the prototype functions, and removed the `return { Init: Init, Callback : Callback };` piece everything seems to work fine.

```
function Refinements() {}

Refinements.prototype.Init = function() {
    $('.btn').click(this.Callback);
};

Refinements.prototype.Callback = function() {
    alert('default function');
};


var refinements = new Refinements();
refinements.Callback = function(){ alert('new method'); };
refinements.Init();​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qyhrb/8/

Answer (score 1):

```
Foobar = function() {
    this.callBack = function() {
        alert("Default method");
    };
}

Foobar.prototype = {
    Init: function() {
        var self = this;
        $(".btn").click(function() {
            self.callBack.call();
        });
    }
};

var foobar = new Foobar();
foobar.Init();
foobar.callBack = function() {
    alert("Boo!");
};
```